# python unitests for sanic app

Tags: python, python-unittest, python-asyncio, aiohttp, sanic

I'm building CRUD REST APIs using peewee ORM and sanic(sanic-crud) as app server. Things are working fine. And I wrote couple of unittest cases for the same.

But, I'm facing problem running unittests. The problem is that unittests starts sanic app server and stalled there. Its not running unittest cases at all. But when I press Ctrl+C manually then the sanic server gets terminated and unittests execution starts. So, it means there should be a way to start sanic server and continue unittests run and terminate server at the end.

Can someone please me the correct way writting unittest cases for sanic app?

I followed official docs too but no luck. 
http://sanic.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sanic/testing.html

I tried following

```
from restapi import app # the execution stalled here i guess
import unittest
import asyncio
import aiohttp

class AutoRestTests(unittest.TestCase):
    ''' Unit testcases for REST APIs '''

    def setUp(self):
        self.loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        asyncio.set_event_loop(None)

    def test_get_metrics_all(self):
        @asyncio.coroutine
        def get_all():
            res = app.test_client.get('/metrics')
            assert res.status == 201
        self.loop.run_until_complete(get_all())
```

from restapi.py

```
app = Sanic(__name__)
generate_crud(app, [Metrics, ...])
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=1337, workers=4, debug=True)
```

Comment: `app.run` should be called inside an `if __name__ == '__main__':` block.

Comment: @dirn how to import app into tests file then?

Comment: The import doesn't change.

Comment: @dirn, it didnt help much. Please check my updated problem description.

Comment: The problem is that you're starting the server. `app.test_client` doesn't make http requests to the server. If you move the `app.run` call into the if that I mentioned, the server won't run when your tests import the app.

Comment: @dirn, thanks ..you are right

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Finally managed to run unittests by moving app.run statement to main block

```
# tiny app server starts here
app = Sanic(__name__)
generate_crud(app, [Metrics, ...])
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=1337, debug=True)
        # workers=4, log_config=LOGGING)
```

and

```
from restapi import app
import json
import unittest

class AutoRestTests(unittest.TestCase):
    ''' Unit testcases for REST APIs '''

    def test_get_metrics_all(self):
        request, response = app.test_client.get('/metrics')
        self.assertEqual(response.status, 200)
        data = json.loads(response.text)
        self.assertEqual(data['metric_name'], 'vCPU')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```